# identify which row caused exception in c#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a datatable and we fetch values from one database, put them in a datatable and insert them into another database. I am using the execute query method of sql and stored procedures to insert data. If one row has a string or binary data truncated error can we identify this using c# and printing that row on console??

Basically, everything is fine in dt but when I insert it I will get exception. Can I get the detail row which is causing exception?

Can anyone guide me on how to proceed with this? I need to know the exact row which is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know which specific row is causing the error, you'll probably have to `foreach` loop through it.

```
foreach(DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows) {
    //Check for the issue.
}
```

This will loop through each DataRow in your table. You'll have to check each individual cell, but you can't foreach loop through it, you'll have to do it manually based on the row. For example, if you know each Column name, you can do:

```
if(row["whatever"]...) // you want to check for the issue here.
```

You can also do:

```
int len = yourDataTable.Columns.Count;
foreach(DataRow row in yourDataTable.Rows) {
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        //Check based in row[i] for your problem.
    }
}
```

That will loop through each row, then each cell in each row based on index. You'll have to do your comparison based on the type received, though, which you'll have to determine based on the contents of your DataTable.

Comment: thanks fo the response,i tried the foreach loop method and used the has errors method but this dint help me out, i dont know which column has error. can you elaborate what does check based in row[i] meaning ????

Comment: No. row[i] will contain the specific data in that DataRow in that cell. So, if I have a 3x3 table, on the second DataRow, row[1] will be the center cell. You will need to check the specific contents of that cell each and every time. Since each cell can be anything, it's set to type of object as well, so you'll also have to determine the type before you do any checking.

Comment: can you please show me a example to check each cell i.e. row[i]

Comment: I don't know how your data is setup. Since this is such a specific case, I would write my code based on the data I am checking. So, for example, if column 1 is an int, and column 2 is a string, etc., I can immediately cast them into what I want based on the row index. In the `foreach` loop, I would just do `if((int)row[0] == whatever` and `if((string)row[1].Equals(whatever)`, etc.

Comment: in this case i should be knowing the column data which i am receving right? actually i dont know which column has what value, neverthless i will give it a try and let u know thanks

Comment: You don't know what value they have, but you should know what type (int, string, etc.) they are, so you can immediately cast them into the appropriate type, then check them however you want to determine what the issue is.